# how to sum the values in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

its basicly product system and i am working on last step checkout and at the end i have to show the total saving 
i am trying to sum a value after getting from database as bellow

```
    <?php
include 'umarfarooq.php';

$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `user-id`='$userid'");
while($abc=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
$quan=$abc['quantity'];
    $bookid=$abc['book-id'];


$chktemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tampbook` WHERE `book-id`='$bookid'");
while($dtype=mysql_fetch_array($chktemp))
{
    $type=$dtype['producttype'];

}

if($type=='book')
{
    $sd=mysql_query("SELECT * from `book` WHERE `book-id`='$bookidfarooq'");
    while($umar=mysql_fetch_array($sd))
    {
        $save=$umar['save'];
        $save=$save*$quan;

        $tot=$tot+$save;

    }
}
else
{

    $sd=mysql_query("SELECT * from `journal` WHERE `book-id`='$bookid'");
    while($umar=mysql_fetch_array($sd))
    {
        $save2=$['save'];
        $save2=$save2*$quanumar;
        $tot2=$tot2+$save2;
    }
}
}


echo $tot+$tot2;



?>
```

The output is

```
18010
```

which is wrong since the correct output is

```
190
```

so what is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps add some other echo statements to see which condition the code is executing.  Or stop your code and view the variable values

Comment: Have you tried echoing the variables before adding to check you are getting the expected values from the database?

Comment: There are so many problems with this code, it's hard to pick one..

Comment: i cleaned it now check it.

Comment: @user3081499 renaming variables isn't a particular efficient way to "clean it"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change like this. I think your total variable contain string type. floatval convert string to float http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
echo floatval($totumar)+floatval($totumar2);
```

Comment: @user3081499 this is poor feedback

Comment: check your variable with is_numeric function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: both is nomeric i checked!!